# how can I run some commands to select template for new created file in vim?

Tags: vim

I am new to vim and want to learn some interesting features about template. Now I have a c template and in my vimrc:

```
if has("autocmd")
    augroup templates
        autocmd BufNewFile *.c 0r ~/.vim/templates/skeleton.c
    augroup END
endif
```

however, I don't want to open every c file with this template (maybe I have many templates for different c files) and want to have some commands to select between different templates. How to achieve that goal? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Sounds like you want snippets. For this you need some snippet plugin like [miniSnip](https://github.com/Jorengarenar/miniSnip) or [UltiSnips](https://github.com/sirver/UltiSnips)

Comment: https://vi.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with a list of requirements:

- each time we edit a new C file, we want to…
- insert a template…
- selected from a list…
- constructed from the content of a specific directory.

Let's do it, from the bottom up.

### Directory layout

`~/.vim/templates/skeleton.<extension>` allows us to have several "skeletons" for a given extension. I tend to prefer doing things based on filetype instead but the extension makes more sense in this case so we will keep your layout.

### List the files in a given directory

Whenever we need a built-in function, our first stop should be either `:help function-list`, which groups every built-in function by topic, or directly `:help <topic>-functions` if we are familiar with that grouping. In this case, we find the following line under `:help file-function`:

```
readdir()               get a List of file names in a directory
```

Indeed, `:help readdir()` is just what we need but, unfortunately (and undocumentedly), it doesn't expand environment variables or tildes on its own so we we have to `:help expand()` our directory path.

We can do:

```
:let templates = readdir(expand('~/.vim/templates/'))
:echo templates
```

to get something like:

```
['foo.c', 'bar.c', 'baz.h']
```

or we can only return the files with a `.c` extension:

```
:let templates = readdir(expand('~/.vim/templates/'), {name -> name =~ '.c$'})
:echo templates
['foo.c', 'bar.c']
```

or we can use the extension of the file associated with the current buffer:

```
:let templates readdir(expand('~/.vim/templates/'), {name -> name =~ '.' . expand('%:e') . '$'})
:echo templates
['foo.c', 'bar.c']
```

Done.

### Select from the list

Again we turn to Vim for a clue. Under `:help interactive-functions` we find the following promising function:

```
inputlist()     let the user pick an entry from a list
```

First, let's get acquainted with `:help inputlist()`.

```
:echo inputlist(['Choose:', '1. foo', '2. bar', '3. baz'])
```

which looks like:

```
Choose:
1. foo
2. bar
3. baz
Type number and <Enter> or click with the mouse (q or empty cancels):
```

and prints the chosen number.

Let's make it more useful by using the file listing command from before:

```
:let templates = readdir(expand('~/.vim/templates/'), {name -> name =~ '.' . expand('%:e') . '$'})
:echo inputlist(['Choose a template:'] + templates)
```

which looks like:

```
Choose a template:
bar.c
foo.c
Type number and <Enter> or click with the mouse (q or empty cancels):
```

and still prints the chosen number but we don't have a number before each entry. This can be solved with `:help mapnew()`:

```
:let templates = readdir(expand('~/.vim/templates/'), {name -> name =~ '.' . expand('%:e') . '$'})
:let templates_for_display = templates->mapnew({idx, val -> 1 + idx . '. ' . val})
:echo inputlist(['Choose a template:'] + templates_for_display)
```

which looks like:

```
Choose a template:
1. bar.c
2. foo.c
Type number and <Enter> or click with the mouse (q or empty cancels):
```

and still prints the chosen number. What is left at this stage is to print the actual item in `templates`. Since lists are zero-based and we had to offset by one to get an intuitive display, we only need to subtract 1 to the number returned by `inputlist()`:

```
:let templates = readdir(expand('~/.vim/templates/'), {name -> name =~ '.' . expand('%:e') . '$'})
:let templates_for_display = templates->mapnew({idx, val -> 1 + idx . '. ' . val})
:let choice = inputlist(['Choose a template:'] + templates_for_display)
:echo templates[choice - 1]
```

which correctly prints `bar.c` or `foo.c`.

We are making huge progress!

### Insert the template

`:help :read` is a crude way to insert text from an external source. Here, we will prefer a slightly cleaner way using `:help setline()` and `:help readfile()`.

But first, let's build a full path from the selected template name:

```
:let templates = readdir(expand('~/.vim/templates/'), {name -> name =~ '.' . expand('%:e') . '$'})
:let templates_for_display = templates->mapnew({idx, val -> 1 + idx . '. ' . val})
:let choice = inputlist(['Choose a template:'] + templates_for_display)
:let chosen_template = expand('~/.vim/templates/' . templates[choice - 1])
:echo chosen_template
```

which should print something like:

```
~/.vim/templates/foo.c
```

We can now read the file:

```
:let templates = readdir(expand('~/.vim/templates/'), {name -> name =~ '.' . expand('%:e') . '$'})
:let templates_for_display = templates->mapnew({idx, val -> 1 + idx . '. ' . val})
:let choice = inputlist(['Choose a template:'] + templates_for_display)
:let chosen_template = expand('~/.vim/templates/' . templates[choice - 1])
:let template_content = readfile(chosen_template)
:echo template_content
```

and, finally, insert it in the buffer:

```
:let templates = readdir(expand('~/.vim/templates/'), {name -> name =~ '.' . expand('%:e') . '$'})
:let templates_for_display = templates->mapnew({idx, val -> 1 + idx . '. ' . val})
:let choice = inputlist(['Choose a template:'] + templates_for_display)
:let chosen_template = expand('~/.vim/templates/' . templates[choice - 1])
:let template_content = readfile(chosen_template)
:call setline(1, template_content)
```

Let's put it all together in a function in our `vimrc`:

```
function SelectTemplate()
    let templates = readdir(expand('~/.vim/templates/'), {name -> name =~ '.' . expand('%:e') . '$'})
    let templates_for_display = templates->mapnew({idx, val -> 1 + idx . '. ' . val})
    let choice = inputlist(['Choose a template:'] + templates_for_display)
    let chosen_template = expand('~/.vim/templates/' . templates[choice - 1])
    let template_content = readfile(chosen_template)
    call setline(1, template_content)
endfunction
```

and test it from a `c` file:

```
:call SelectTemplate()
```

Great! We are almost done!

### Automatisation

For the last step, we can simply use your snippet with a couple of minor changes:

```
if has("autocmd")
    augroup templates
        autocmd!
        autocmd BufNewFile *.c call SelectTemplate()
    augroup END
endif
```

Phew! What a ride!

### What, now?

- The function could be refined a little by removing duplication and adding checks here and there.
- Which should make it possible to use `*` in the autocommand so that it works on any file extension.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer, the whole process makes sense but there is only one problem that I can't find mapnew function in my vim. I tried to just use map but everytime I select a number, it displays that 'cannot open file 1', it seems like chosen_template doesn't expand as expected.

Comment: `mapnew()` is a recent addition. If you can't upgrade or don't want to, you can replace it with `:help deepcopy()` and `:help map()`: `templates->deepcopy()->map(…)`.

Comment: I tested it and found that a bug existed in 'expand('~/.vim/templates/' + templates[choice - 1])'. It always returns 0 in my computer. so I modified it as below: let chosen_template = '~/.vim/templates/' . templates[choice - 1]   let template_content = readfile(glob(chosen_template))  and it works fine now.

Comment: Dear god, it's `.` for concatenation, not `+`. My JavaScript and VimScript wires got crossed again!